# Does focal length of lens change with change in refractive index?

Tags: optics, refraction, lenses

If there are two identical lenses L1 and L2 but made with different materials such that refractive index of one is greater than the other (Say for L1 = 1.33 and L2 = 2.13). Will it affect in any way? Is there a change in focal length or where the image is formed? Please explain.

Comment: Yes, the focal length is dependent on the optical density of the material. See- Lens Maker's Formula

Answer (score 1):

A lens works because it has a different refractive index from the medium it is in.  The bigger that difference, the stronger the lens is for a given shape.

That also means the focal length of a glass lens in air is less than its focal length in water.  The smaller difference in refractive index makes it weaker.

Comment: So, the focal length doesn't have to be half of the Radius of curvature (I have seen the relation R= 2f )?

Comment: The relationship $R=2f$ is for a concave mirror, not for a lens.